# How to apply color for default keyword in div dynamically using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to apply the color for default SQL keywords dynamically.Example:-while user enter the word in the div as like words are "select * from table", i need to show words of select, from and table as blue color and irrespective of default words, i need to show as default color.Kindly provide the solution for this.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: _Kindly provide the solution for this_ haha, wrong site. You can find people who do the work for you on freelancer.com

Comment: So you have an html text area or an input and as a user types you want the color of his word to change if the word he types is equal to one of your key words?

Comment: @Harry yes...I have ContentEditable div,i got active child element text and trying to apply color for default color.

Comment: @Jai - you're getting "negative reputation" because you haven't posted code showing what you've tried to do to accomplish your goal. It seems to me that you might have something to post in terms of code? We'll help you through the big challenges.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement this, you can create an array of the keywords for which you want to change the color. Whenever you find a space on keypress you take the last word and match it within the array of keyword. If it matches apply the css.

It's just and idea to get on.

Comment: Ok @vijay mishra ...i can implement but i am trying span means it takes the entire div as blue color.

Comment: Dude, you should have cleared this at first and should have posted your code. Any way, if that is the case you can wrap that element with some tag like <p></p> and then apply css to this. Also, if you are sending that query for execution later in your backend you need to remove all tags. I hope, I could be of your help.